# How to log to the console in an LLDB data formatter

Tags: python, xcode, logging, lldb

I've written an LLDB data formatter but I could not get my log output to show in the Xcode lldb console. The [data formatter examples](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/synthetic/gnu_libstdcpp.py) create the logger and write to it like so:

```
def __init__(self, valobj, dict):
    logger = lldb.formatters.Logger.Logger()
    ...
    logger >> "Providing synthetic children for a vector named " + str(valobj.GetName())
```

I did that and I enabled the lldb formatters log with the command

```
log enable -g lldb formatters
```

When I then printed a variable (e.g. with `frame var x`) I did see a lot of debug output, but not mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured it out [by looking at the Logger source](http://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/lldb.formatters.Logger-pysrc.html#Logger.__init__) in more detail.

1. To enable logging at all, you have to set `lldb.formatters.Logger._lldb_formatters_debug_level` to a value larger than 0. Quoting from the source itself:

   - *if you define it to any value greater than 1, the log will be automatically flushed after each write (slower but should make sure most of the stuff makes it to the log even if we crash)*
   - *if you define it to any value greater than 2, the calling function's details will automatically be logged (even slower, but provides additional details)*
2. By default, `lldb.formatters.Logger` will print to stdout. If you're debugging with Xcode, you will not see lldb's stdout stream. If you want to log to a file, set `lldb.formatters.Logger._lldb_formatters_debug_filename` to the desired filename. Attention: You have to make sure the file is writable and you must not set it to a path that requires shell expansion (e.g. ~/logfile.log will not work, Python does not expand the ~).

In summary, my `__lldb_init_module` looks like this:

```
def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    lldb.formatters.Logger._lldb_formatters_debug_level = 2
    lldb.formatters.Logger._lldb_formatters_debug_filename = "/Users/Shared/lldb.py.log"

    # followed by debugger.HandleCommand(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is unfortunately a known issue

Since LLDB does not expose SB API for its own logging mechanism, the lldb.formatters.Logger uses a logging logic that is separate from the "log enable" command

If all you are trying to do is debug a data formatter as you write it, you could just use "print" statements inside the formatter body

Comment: But where do these print to? I realize, I can always print to a file, but I hoped there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: Or can I direct the lldb.formatters.Logger to a useful location?

Comment: I see: print goes to stdout of course, which I won't see when Xcode has started lldb. And I can set `_lldb_formatters_debug_filename` to print to a log file.